# How to make this decryption in php

Tags: php, asp.net

This is my sample code in asp.net:

```
 CryptoStream cryptoStream;
 Rijndael rijndael = Rijndael.Create();
 Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, SALT);
 rijndael.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
 rijndael.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
 memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
 cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, rijndael.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
cryptoStream.Write(cipher, 0, cipher.Length);
 cryptoStream.Close();`enter code here`
  return memoryStream.ToArray();
```

any help would be appreciated.